# When an answer gets accepted, should the *question* be edited into the actual *answer*?

Tags: discussion, support, editing, accepted-answer

Unlike on other Stack Exchange sites, questions posted in Puzzling Stack Exchange very commonly receive answers where the authors of the answers aren't 100% sure that their solution is correct, as even if they gave great answers, the *intended* solution *(which, on PSE, is classified as the "correct" solution)* may differ. Actually, come to think about it, it is impossible to be 100% sure of our answers before the OP reveals the intended solution.

This leads to answers on PSE to be actual questions directing at the OP *(love the irony!)*, like:

---

Is the answer

> bubbles?

---

*My* question is:

Once the OP of the questions accepts an answer that is posed as a question, is it appropriate to edit out the question in the answer and replace it with a statement?

For example, the above example will be edited into:

---

The answer is:

> bubbles

---

This may be unnecessary, but there *are* times where I see a good puzzle & accepted answer, and feel like the answer should be more confident for the readers.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO the checkmark is clear enough to indicate that the answer is correct, even though it's posed in the way you describe. There's no need to bump the thread by making a minor edit.